# NullReferenceException was unhandled HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, nullreferenceexception, windows-phone, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to get headers from a user provided url and all seems to be working fine until I try `http://www.google.com` which gives me the following exception:

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled Message=NotSupportedException
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Net.Browser.OHWRAsyncResult.get_AsyncWaitHandle()
>          at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
>          at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>          at Network_Monitor.Checks.URLCheckResults.RespCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
>          at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.b__8(Object state2)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
>          at System.Threading.Timer.ring()

Call Stack:

```
System.Windows.dll!System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, object state) + 0xc3 bytes 
System.Windows.dll!System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) + 0x41 bytes 
Network Monitor.dll!Network_Monitor.Checks.URLCheckResults.RespCallback(System.IAsyncResult asynchronousResult) Line 55 + 0x3 bytes C#
System.Windows.dll!System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InvokeGetResponseCallback.AnonymousMethod__8(object state2) + 0x1b bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(object state) + 0x18 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x63 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(object o) + 0x47 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Timer.ring() + 0x70 bytes
```

I've Googled for hours looking for the solution but none of the existing ones work. What is cause this to appear for Google.com but not other websites?

```
public void CheckURL(String URL)
{
    lblResults.Text = "Checking...";

    var wr = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
    wr.Method = "HEAD";

    IAsyncResult asyncResult = (IAsyncResult)wr.BeginGetResponse(RespCallback, wr);
}

private void RespCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult))
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        if (!lblResults.Text.Equals("Checking..."))
                        {
                            lblResults.Text += "\n";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lblResults.Text = "";
                        }

                        lblResults.Text += "Header Name:" + response.Headers.AllKeys[i] + ", Header value :" + response.Headers[response.Headers.AllKeys[i]];
                    }
                });
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        if (((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                lblResults.Text = "Page Not Found (404)";
            });
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Program Name", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is happening on the line `using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult))` with the following screenshot (Right Click and click view image to see it bigger):

[image: Exception Image]

Comment: by headers, do you mean the actual content of a <header> tag in html? if so, going on googles home page and searching for the word header in the source code does not show any results, which might explain the NullReferenceException?

Comment: No, the HttpWebResponse headers (the reason I'm using "HEAD")

Comment: @LukeWyatt I don't know what to say. Create that as an answer and I'll reward you the +100 reputation.

Comment: You can cut the amount of the reward.  It wasn't really worth a 100 bounty for working code.

Comment: It won't let me but that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ME: It just ran for me perfectly using yahoo.com, google.com, and
>   msn.com. The only difference between mine and your code was I ran the
>   iteration outside of the Dispatcher. Any chance Google was hiccuping
>   when you tried?
>
> Gabriel: I don't know what to say. Create that as an answer and I'll
>   reward you the +100 reputation.